# How to handle Auth token expiry situation without

Tags: java, oauth, jjwt

I need one help related to Auth Token Expiry.
I have one access token whose expiry is 30 minutes. As I am used doing something/some activity till 30 minutes .
Now my token expired , at 30th minutes I called the service to fetch all users but at this time my tokes was expired .
So how to handle this situation.
1. Do i allow the application to fetch the users List with expired token ? 
2. Should I regenerate the token sent back to browser ,stored in LocalStorage and call the service again.?

Note: While doing this User should not know that application token expired.This all should be done in Asynchronous manner.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a refresh token? What you need is an API interceptor which can catch the 403 error response and can request for a new token using the refresh token that you have stored. You can then trigger the request again using the new token.

Comment: No. I am not using refresh token. THe situation is i need to do 2 task is 1. update/generate/refresh the token and 2. also cater the user request.  This both thing should be handle in one click only.